# Loop through divs with for loop and sql COUNT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop

CODE :

```
$result= mysql_query ("SELECT COUNT(post_id) AS postCounter FROM headlines WHERE user_id= '$_SESSION[user_id]' ");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows ($result);

if ($numrows!=0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
        $postCounter = $row['postCounter'];

    for ($i=1; $i<=$postCounter; $i++){
        echo "$i";
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to know is "How could I use for-loop to echo div's depending on the COUNT result?"

So if `$postCounter` above was "4" I need to display 4 divs for it .

Comment: you are already doing it where is the issue ?

Comment: yes am doing it but what to do next here's my question if i want to echo number of divs depending on COUNT result

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_fetch_array` in a loop? The query only returns one row.

Comment: Echo a `DIV` in the body of the `for` loop. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar it's working fine with me it's return all the rows !

Comment: But it's unnecessary. You just need to call it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `for` loop, echo a `DIV` instead of just echoing the number.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $postCounter; $i++) {
    echo "<div>$i</div>";
}
```

Comment: ok now it's working good but i wont the number of $i echoed too

Comment: I'm echoing `$i` inside the DIV.

Comment: thank you @Barmar for the help it's exactly what am looking for

Comment: another Q can i style the div in the for-loop or put the value of "<div $i></div>" in a variable ?

Comment: You can do whatever you want. Whatever you echo will be put in the web page. Or you can concatenate the strings to a variable. It's just basic PHP coding, you need to read tutorials. Please don't expect me to teach you how to program.

Answer (score -1):

An other way you can do by FOREACH to embed html into php

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($postcounter as $post) { ?>
    <li><?php echo $post; ?></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this help

Comment: `$postcounter` is a number, not an array, you can't use it with `foreach`.

Comment: Where is the `DIV` in your answer?

Comment: You can replace ul and li with any html tag And foreach can be replace by for. I just tried to give a example for using HTML in PHP

Comment: that's the best approach but when am doing it i got duplicate result

Comment: @harry you're right its gonna work if i just want to echo the result of postContent not postCounter .

Comment: The OP is obviously totally clueless. You can't really expect him to figure out how to change things from your answer so that they work for his needs.